# How to make Android Client be FIPS compliant without third party SDK, but leverage Native APIs?

Tags: android, frameworks, fips

My Android App wants to have support for FIPS without using third party sdk but want to use specifically want to use or leverage Native APIs from Android Framework ?
Any inputs from expert will helpful

Exepecting how can we use if at all any Native APIs from Android Framework used for FIPS support and what are retriction is FIPS licesence will be complaint to use.

If any limitation at all. Share information to leverage Android Framework API for FIPS support.